# Is there a limit to pushing to Shift-IR in JTAG?

Tags: arm, jtag

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of JTAG with ARM.
In particular, there is a Shift-IR stage in the JTAG as shown below,

[image]

As far as I know, at this Shift-IR stage, we can push instructions like ABORT, DPACC, APACC, IDCODE, BYPASS.
These IR commands are only 4bits like 4'b0000, 4'b0001, 4'b0011, 4'b0111, 4'b1111..which means I have to push it with 4 times tck.
[image]

I came across that Shift-IR is implemented with 8bits not 4bits to read IDCODE.

```
for (idx=0; idx<4; idx=idx+1) //DAP : Shift-IR
dap_1b_push(TMS(0), TDI(1)); 

dap_1b_push(TMS(0), TDI(0));
dap_1b_push(TMS(0), TDI(1));
dap_1b_push(TMS(0), TDI(1));
dap_1b_push(TMS(1), TDI(1)); //DAP : Exit IR
```

From above, the Shift-IR for the IDCODE is implemented with 8 pushes. Only the last 4 digits are entered, no matter how many times I push in Shift-IR?
Is there any reason? push 4bits before push IR command?

[Update question]

I have updated the question as I missed to add information.
Currently, there are 2 devices connected with JTAG(a.k.a Daisy Chain)  ARM R5 and ARM CS400(Coresight-400). They have connected like TDI->R5->CS400->TDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember a JTAG chain in Shift-IR state is just a big shift register of all concatenated instruction registers where bits are inserted from TDI pin and output is on TDO pin of the board connector.

I don't know where you got your example from, but this would typically be used in a JTAG chain where another TAP with a 4-bit instruction register is connected after the JTAG-DP you are targetting, on its TDO pin. The loop shifting "1111" would then shift a Bypass instruction to this other TAP. This is typically the case with STM32s which have two TAPs internally, one for boundary scan, and one for Cortex debug.

Now for the questions: If you only have one TAP in the chain with only a 4-bit instruction register, then yes, only the four last bit shifted will be taken into account when you go through the Update-IR state. Any other reason would be to have more than one TAP in the chain.

[Update after the update in question]

Update confirms it: having R5 and CS400 just makes a JTAG chain of two JTAG-DPs, so the "1111" header is really there to bypass the CS400's TAP.